# How does Sanger sequencing resolve two bands with equal size?

Tags: dna-sequencing

In Sanger sequencing, how can we read the sequence if we have 2 bands with the same size?

Comment: I can see now how this would be a homework question, although the answer is dependent on the full context which you haven't given us.  Please read the site's [policy on homework questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), which requires you to demonstrate having tried to find an answer. Also please note that Sanger was a (very famous) person and his name is spelled with a capital S (which is also used at the begining of sentences in English).

Comment: The band size by itself isn't relevant, unless you are using the same primers for PCR as sequencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens if your sample contains a mix of two DNA molecules, with different bases at a certain position.

In your case, you would have a mixture of ACTGGCTA and ACTGTCTA.

In real life, the "double band" would be half as intense as the other single bands, as the signal is "divided by two".